# How can I refer to multiple equations with "Eq. (i)" style?

Tags: paper-submission, writing-style, formatting

Assume the manuscript format for referencing the equations is as "Eq. (i)". How can I properly refer to multiple equations at once? For example which of the followings is more acceptable?

1. In Eq. (1), Eq. (2), Eq. (3), and Eq. (4)
2. In Eq. (1,2,3,4) or Eq. (1-4)
3. In Eqs. (1,2,3,4)
4. Any better idea?

Comment: If you wanna publish in a journal, you can check the author guidelines. Most journals have style guides for formatting and/or even style sheets, e.g. for LaTeX.

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog it's for a conference paper, but they only specified the single-form reference style.

Comment: My next advice would have been to check in previous papers of the conference what is used there but @jon-custer already included that advice in the answer.

Comment: Why do you use brackets when referencing at all? When numbering, the brackets assure that you do not mistake the number for a part of the actual equation and give some kind of highlighting, so they make sense there. But when referencing, they have no purpose and just add clutter, making your text more difficult to read. Writing “Eq. 1” already makes it perfectly clear what you are referencing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my old copy of the AIP style guides (American Institute of Physics) they use (Section IV Mathematical Expressions, C. Displayed Equations, 2. Equation numbers) the format of

> Eqs. (3)-(5)

in their text.

But, as noted, check the author guidelines or style sheet of your particular journal (or just look in the articles for an example).

Comment: I will use that, and you want to use an EN dash between the numbering of the equations,, since you are enumerating a range